# How to test for encoding type Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem I am having regarding foreign characters (any and all alphabets).  My script (2.7 python) receives the characters (mix of english alphabet and other foreign characters) as unicode json, and it is sent to a database insert function for insertion into some tables using psycopg2.  This works perfect as a script, but once not so much as a service (foreign chars get inserted as nonsense).  This unicoding/encoding/decoding stuff is so confusing!  I am trying to follow along with this ( https://www.pythoncentral.io/python-unicode-encode-decode-strings-python-2x/ )  in the hopes of understanding what I am receiving exactly and then sending to the database, but it seems to me that I need to know what the encoding is at various stages.  How do you GET what the encoding type is?  Sorry, this must be so simple, but I am not finding how to get that info, and other's questions on this matter haven't exactly been answered, in my opinion.  This can't be that elusive.  Please help.

Add-on info as requested...
-Yes, would love to move to 3.x, but cannot for now.
-Currently it is mostly me testing, it's not live for users yet.  I am testing and developing from a Windows 2012 Server AWS machine, and the service is hosted on a similar machine.
So yes - how do you find the locale info?

Have done some testing with the frontend dev (js) and he states the json input is coming to me as url encoded... when I type it, it just says unicode.  Thoughts??

Comment: If your code works as a script, but not as a service, that suggests that the problem lies in the locale settings of the user that is executng the code.  For example, your user may use a locale setting with a unicode-friendly encoding but the system user that runs the service might use a different locale that mangles your unicode.  Can you edit your question to include the operating system that the code is executing on?  Then perhaps people can explain how to find the necessary locale information.

Comment: If possible, I'd suggest moving to python 3.x, the unicode support is significantly more robust than python 2.7

Comment: To get locale info: `import locale;print(locale.getlocale())`.  Url-encoding (or percent-encoding) can be decoded using [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) and similar tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on what the default system encoding is. Instead, always set it yourself:

```
    # read in a string (a bunch of bytes the encoding of which you should know)
    str = sys.stdin.read();
    # decode the bytes into a unicode string
    u = unicode.decode(str, encoding='ISO-8859-1', errors=replace);
    # do stuff with the string
    # ...
    # always operate on unicode stuff inside your program.
    # make a 'unicode sandwhich'.
    # ...
    # encode the bytes in preparation for writing them out
    out = unicode.encode(u, encoding='UTF-8')
    # great, now you have bytes you can just write out
    with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
        rb.write(out)
```

Notice, I hard-coded the encoding throughout.

But what if you don't know the encoding of the input? Well, that's a problem. [You need to know that](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). But I also understand unicode can be painful and there's this guy from the python community who tells you [how to stop the pain (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc).

Note, one of the BIG changes in python 3 is better unicode support. Instead of using the `unicode` package and the confusing py2 `str` type, in python 3 `str` type is just what python 2's `unicode` type was, and you can specify encodings in more convenient places:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w', encoding=UTF-8, errors='ignore') as f:
   # ...
```